# Graphql apollo-client ios batch request

Tags: ios, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, gql

I'm working on an application which use the "apollo-graphql-client".

I'm trying to send a batch request (multiple queries/ mutation in a single request), and so far I'm only familiar about sending a single query.

Is it possible? There is no documentation regarding batch request for ios in the apollo-client docs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Batching can be done as a single query / mutation with this graphql request structure:

```js
mutation {
  M1: createUser(ID: "21959d03-564b-4fab-9cef-a6cb771ac016"){
    ID
    Name
  }
  M2: createUser(ID: "00b8d317-eb26-4e63-807c-2345ce246316") {
    ID
    Name
  }
}
```